# Qt Table Model Example

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I'm looking at the Qt example "Table Model Example"

In that example, the createConnection() method in connection.h contains the following code:

```
static bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if (!db.open()) {...
```

I duplicated this example in my code. I don't understand 2 things about it.

1. The local variable db is destroyed at the end of the createConnection() function (see RAII). Since my database doesn't need to be initialized and I'm not using the "db" variable, I can't see why I need this code. However, if I remove it, I my program fails to read from my existing database. I would expect the destruction of the db would close the database and make it unavailable. However, since I don't touch the db variable, why does it need to be created then destroyed before I can access the database? Since I don't use the db variable anywhere and it is destroyed before my code is called, I fail to see why I need to call the createConnection() function at all. On the other hand, I don't see how to open the database and cause the variable destruction to have exception safe RAII code.
2. I never get db.open() to fail. If I don't have the database, it creates it then opens a blank one. If I do have the database, it opens it. I have a database and if for any reason it fails to open, I don't want it created, I want an error since something is seriously wrong. Opening a blank database can only be trouble for me. How do I handle this case?

I'm new to Qt, but very experienced in C++. This code makes little sense to me. I would expect the db variable's lifetime be the lifetime of the open database.  As coded in the example, I fail to see how this code isn't having a resource leak. From what I can tell, initializing db opens some sort of global resource and keeps it open even after the db variable is destroyed causing a leak.

This is very confusing.

Thx.

H Os Tile

Comment: `QSqlDatabase` is a rather weird class. Read up on its documentation: it doesn't act the way you think it does. It's not a RAII class.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small example.

1. `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` will create the default connection, which will be used by any subsequent query not explicit naming another connection. The connection will not be destroyed upon scope end. In this example, the `createConnection()` will be used to initialize the inMemory Database. The connection could be later on retrieved using `QSqlDatabase::database()`. In standard applications one would probably keep the `QSqlDatabase db` as a class member.
2. Using inMemory db just creates an empty db, as it is for SQLite-file based db. If you want to check for an existing file (db) use `QFile::exists(QString path)`.

If you were to open many databases (with different connection names on `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","anotherConnectionName");` you would have a leak. Otherwise you are just overwriting the default database connection. QApplication itself will keep the connections. They can be explicit removed using `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()`;

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are saying here. I'm unclear why the inMemory db makes things different. My code was duplicated from the example and does not make anything "inMemory" and it creates the database all the same. The Sqlite docs say SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE will return an error the database must already exist, otherwise an error is returned. Also, making db a member would seem to move the lifetime from the variable to the instance of the wrapper, so I can't see how that helps. Sounds like Qt isn't thread safe or support exceptions? I think I'm worse off in my understanding now.

Comment: The documentations states the thread safety by class. Exceptions are supported but not widely implemented due to compatibility issues on older compilers. This probably will change with Qt 5.7 a lot.

Comment: As stated by KubaOber QSqlDatabase is kind of special. If you do create a `QSqlQuery` or similar classes (`QSqlTable`,...) and do not provide a database handle Qt will automatically use the default connection. This makes querying the database actually pretty easy. One thing to mention is, the sql connection itself is not threadsafe. You should open a connection for every thread you intend to directly query the database.

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlDatabase` is a rather weird class. Read up on its documentation. The connection persists, and a `QSqlDatabase` is a handle to it. The connections are named, and `addDatabase` returns the connection with a given name, and optionally creates it if it doesn't exist. You can have any number of `QSqlDatabase` objects represent one connection.

Since sqlite in-memory databases are specific to your process, there's very little point in not creating one when you ask for it. The only way for you to create it ahead of time would be using sqlite api directly, from your process. These databases don't persist. The behavior here is quite sensible.

Comment: Retype: In my case my database is on disk and must exist before my application starts so the behavior is not sensible. A missing database must be diagnosed reliably and reported to the user. This must also be true if multiple programs are started at the same time. The doc says nothing about thread safety for these functions. Since it doesn't report an error and creates the database on disk when missing, it must not be thread safe regardless of the docs silence on the topic. Sad that it leaks resources and isn't exception safe too. Qt should have stuck with RAII like a good C++ library should.

Comment: @HOsTile As long as you use a connection from a single thread at a time, you're good. Your question doesn't deal with on-disk databases: if you wanted to ask something else, for the love of all that is holy, do so.

Comment: @HOsTile I can't read your mind. If you have to comment to explain what it is you're really doing (namely: nothing about an in-memory database), then it indicates your question needs fixing...